# Reser styles and overrule stylesheet with inline CSS

Tags: css

I have a stylesheet that sets the text of a H3 tag to transform to uppercase.

I want to use a h3 tag which has all the same properties of that on my stylesheet but doesn't do the text-transform.

If it was a case of a different font size or colour it would be easy as I could just write the change into an inline bit of code. However I haven't been able to find something like a text-transform that isn't anything other than uppercase, lowercase or capitalise. Is there something like 'reset' or 'normal' that I can apply inline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `text-transform: none` to reset the uppercase styling.

Comment: Great! Simple and useful, thanks - I will mark this as accepted in 9 mins when it lets me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text-transform:none` or `text-transform:capitalize` if you need the first char to uppercase.